React App Fails to Upload Video to API but Works with Python/Postman - CORS or Axios Issue?
Question:
I'm working on a React application that captures a 30-second video from the user's camera, then uploads it to an API endpoint for health metrics analysis. The backend is built with FastAPI and has CORS enabled. When testing the same API with Python or Postman, everything works perfectly, but in my React app, the live upload consistently fails, BUT upload file from device works.
Note: I am backend developer with little knowledge in React/Frontend. I am trying to figure what is wrong as our frontend guys are struggling.
Setup:

Frontend: React using Axios to handle the video upload.
Backend: FastAPI with CORSMiddleware configured for allow_origins=["*"].
Testing:

Python and Postman successfully upload the video with all required parameters.
React consistently fails with errors, sometimes related to CORS or network.



Backend CORS Setup (FastAPI):
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Allows all origins
    allow_credentials=False,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

React Code (App.js):
I use Axios for the HTTP request:
import axios from "axios";

const uploadVideo = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("gender", "Male");
    formData.append("diabetes", "false");
    formData.append("height", 178);
    formData.append("name", "tony");
    formData.append("weight_unit", "kgs");
    formData.append("smoke", "false");
    formData.append("weight", 79);
    formData.append("height_unit", "cm");
    formData.append("age", 25);
    formData.append("video", videoBlob, "recording.webm");

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            "https://link/process-video/",
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
                withCredentials: false,
            }
        );
        console.log("Response:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading video:", error);
    }
};

My Environment:

React: 10.8.1
FastAPI: fastapi==0.112.0
Testing on Chrome with CORS enabled and disabled, but no success in React.

Problem:
In React, the upload either fails silently or gives a CORS-related error, despite the API being reachable and fully functional through other means (Postman, Python and even React when uploading video from device).
What We have Tried:

Postman Testing: Works perfectly with the same headers and payload.
Python Script: Also works fine with a requests library setup.
CORS Middleware: Double-checked the CORS settings in FastAPI to allow all origins, methods, and headers.
Axios Configuration: Added withCredentials: false to align with the backend's CORS settings and specified Content-Type as multipart/form-data.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue? Is it potentially a problem with React dependencies, Axios, or something in my CORS setup?

Hint.  Look at all HIDDEN headers that postman is sending.

There may be a check box in postman "show/hide auto generated headers"

Where is videoBlob defined? Can you post the errors you get when sending the request from your React app? Does it reach the server in the access log? Can you provide the whole component rather than just the function that handles the HTTP Request?

Does this answer your question?
